# barButtonItem action exception

Tags: ios, exception, uinavigationcontroller

I am setting navigationBarItem in viewDidLoad method

```
var button = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Menu", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, target: self, action: Selector("goToMenu:"))
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button
```

and I have got a method that is selector to this button action

```
func goToMenu() {
    var destinationViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("menuBoard") as MenuViewController
    self.navigationController?.presentViewController(destinationViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

but I have got exception

```
goToMenu:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15678990'
```

what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify code to that:

```
func goToMenu(sender: AnyObject) {
    var destinationViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("menuBoard") as MenuViewController
    self.navigationController?.presentViewController(destinationViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The reason is that your `Selector("goToMenu:")` looks for method that takes one parameter, but your `goToMenu` actually have no parameters